# Find a list of my pre ordered games?

Tags: steam

As some people have wrongly pointed out Pre order games, pre ordered through steam, show up in your library when you purchase them. For example of Prey in my library:

[image: Prey in library]

---

I like to pre-order games every now and then if I like any bonuses, I'm interested in the game, it's on sale etc. I usually keep a bit of money around in case there is a game that is coming out that I like the look of and buy it. For these reasons I tend to have a few games on pre-order at any one time.

Is there anyway I can search my library to find games that are on pre-order automatically?

---

I could add them to their own category but that depends on me remembering to do it and won't work for games in the past if I can't remember where they are. So I'd like a built in way, if there is one.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57489/discussion-on-question-by-thelethalcoder-find-a-list-of-my-pre-ordered-games).

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem as you. I couldn't find a really nice solution to this neither. The current way I use to do it is using a category for pre ordered games.

Sometimes I forget to add them to it aswell. For this case I use [this website](http://www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/steam/) to sort my games by release date. Then I add them to the category.

Currently there isn't a built-in way to sort them. Another way you could try is using the software [depressurizer](https://github.com/rallion/depressurizer). This allows you to automatically sort your games - even by release date.

Comment: I appreciate you can do it this way, as I mentioned in the OP, but I was really looking for something to do it for me.

Comment: Also might be a bug with that website because it shows some of my games on pre-order but not all of them

Comment: This is strange. I added another possible solution.